# Can we pass a custom object from Excel to C# ExcelDNA?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-dna

I have an object:

```
public class Shampoo
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Id {get;set;}
public string PriceRegion {get;set;}
}
```

Can I pass this object to a method in C# via Excel DNA:

C# method is:

```
public static string PassShampoo(Shampoo shampoo)
{
//Some Code...
}
```

Is this possible from VBA to C# via Excel DNA?

Answer (score 2):

Your .NET library can export and register the `Shampoo` class as a COM visible type, which you can then instantiate from VBA as `Dim sh = New Shampoo()`. Similarly other types could be define, like

```
public class Shopper()
{
    public string ReadLabel(Shampoo shampoo)
    {
        return shampoo.Name;
    }
}
```

and then a `New Shopper()` could be passed the `shampoo`:

```
Dim anne As Shopper = New Shopper()
Dim dove As Shampoo = New Shampoo()

Dim label As String
label = anne.ReadLabel(dove)
```

The method using `Shampoo` (`Shopper.ReadLabel` above) would not be `static` and would not be available to Excel as a UDF or anything - just as a method on a .NET object onvoked via COM interop from VBA.

So far - no [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.coodeplex.com) involved. You could do all of this with a standard .NET assembly that is compiled with the right flags and attributes and registered for COM interop on your machine.

However, Excel-DNA also allows your add-in to be a COM Server. This means that the .xll can host the COM classes you've defined in your library, your add-in can do the COM registration (instead of an installer) without requiring Administrator access, and your COM Objects will live in the same AppDomain as the rest of your add-in. So Excel-DNA helps a bit in gluing things up, but the actual interaction between the VBA code and your .NET assembly is the standard .NET-to-COM interop, which works very well once you've climbed the learning curve a bit.